# Изменения в php-файлах не видны без перезагрузки apache

Tags: php, apache

здравствуйте, я установил на свой сервер OPcache (использую связку apache+nginx), после установки, добавил в конфиг пару строк (я взял их из рекомендаций в мануалах)

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.validate_timestamps=0 
opcache.max_accelerated_files=20000
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

но дело в том, что теперь, когда я меняю что либо в php файлах, на сайте это никак не отражается, и помогает только перезагрузка апача

подскажите, это я что-то не так сделал, или так и должно быть?

Comment: не юзал ни разу `opcaсhe` но ваши первые два параметра, очевидно, отключают проверку файлов на изменения. Конечно, после такого не будет изменений никаких при замене файлов.

Comment: В заголовке должна быть суть вопроса, а не «по поводу чего он».

Answer (score 1):

Второй параметр в вашем конфиге `opcache.validate_timestamps` отключает проверку файлов на изменения. Поэтому после обновления файлов вы не видите изменений.
Если вы его включите (`1`), то вступает в работу первый параметр `opcache.revalidate_freq`, указывающий, как часто измеения будут проверяться (в секундах). Если указано значение `0`, то проверка будет осуществляться при каждом запросе..

Возможно для сервера разработки включать OPCache смысла и нет. Что касается продакшен-сервера, то обновления кода здесь  на так часты. Поэтому либо настройте указанные параметры нужным образом. Либо вручную очищайте кэш, используя функции [`opcache_reset()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.opcache-reset.php) и [`opcache_invalidate()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.opcache-invalidate.php). Первая из них очищает кэш целиком, вторая для указанного файла (обновленного в вашем случае).
Загвоздка в том, что данные функции не получится выполнить из консоли, поэтому после обновления сайта из репозитория не получится просто дописать некий хук для обновления кэша, а придется на сайте выполнить некий скрипт, который их выполнит.

*зы: на правильный ответ не претендует, OPCache не использовал. Прочитал доки, полученные знания изложил в ответ.*